# How to solve ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes as my images set is many in the folder

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

when I tried to code the python to help calculate every column of the pixels and calculate every column of the means, the same process goes for every row of the pixels.
I have when I ran the code, it give a warning message that "operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (1000,) (24,) "

```
import os
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image

directory = 'File path'

row_means = []
col_means = []

for filename in os.listdir(directory):
    if filename.endswith('.jpg') or filename.endswith('.png'):
        # open the image and convert it to a NumPy array
        im = Image.open(os.path.join(directory, filename))
        im_array = np.array(im)

        # calculate the mean values for each row and column
        row_means.append(np.mean(im_array, axis=1))
        col_means.append(np.mean(im_array, axis=0))


highest_row_mean = np.max(row_means, axis=1)
lowest_row_mean = np.min(row_means, axis=1)
highest_col_mean = np.max(col_means, axis=0)
lowest_col_mean = np.min(col_means, axis=0)


row_means = [np.subtract(row, highest_row_mean) for row in row_means]
col_means = [np.subtract(col, highest_col_mean) for col in col_means]


mean_row_value = np.mean(row_means, axis=0)
mean_col_value = np.mean(col_means, axis=0)
```

The detailed error is

> in module  row_means = [np.subtract(row, highest_row_mean) for row in row_means]

> in listcomp row_means = [np.subtract(row, highest_row_mean) for row in row_means]

> ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (1000,) (24,)

Comment: Someplace in your code (don't leave us guessing), you have arrays that don't match in shape.  Isn't that obvious :(

Comment: as I know my image set is 3D when I run numpy shape, it shows "shape
(1000, 1356, 3)" is this coding didn't compatible with it? I'm sorry that I don't have any idea for it...

Comment: Did it give you an error message with multiline traceback, or just a warning (without any line information)?  Don't try to summarize the error.

Comment: Hi, I'm sorry for my mistake, please have a check again that I have re-edited my post

Comment: Where the code says `np.subtract(row, highest_row_mean)`, what do you expect this to do, and why? What do you expect `row` and `highest_row_mean` to look like? In particular, what do you expect their dimensions to be? Do you understand (according to the error message) what the dimensions actually are? Do those dimensions make sense? Does the attempt to subtract make sense to you? (What do you think the result should be?)

Comment: Please read [mre] and try to show a simpler example that other people can **copy and paste, without changing or adding anything**, to see the **exact** problem **directly**. For example, instead of building a list, can you cause the problem with data from a single image (making the `subtract` calls directly, rather than in a list comprehension)? Can you cause the problem using a small, hard-coded array, rather than reading from an image file? Can you cause the problem by considering only rows, and skipping the code for columns?

Answer (score 0):

`row_means` is a list of arrays.  `np.array(row_means)` probably will be (24,1000) shape.  Taking this max:

```
highest_row_mean = np.max(row_means, axis=1)
```

results in a (24,) shape array.

In

```
[np.subtract(row, highest_row_mean) for row in row_means]
```

`row` will be a (1000,) array.  `row-highest_row_mean` will then be `(1000,)-(24,)`, and your error.

In instead you do:

```
row_means = np.array(row_means)   # (24,1000)
rowmax = np.max(row_means, axis=1)  # (24,)
row_means = row_means - rowmax[:,None]   # (24,1000)-(24,1)
```

this should work with the list comprehension.

Or use `rowmax = np.max(row_means,axis=1,keepdims=True)` to get the (24,1) shape array.